# All possible degree 3 field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Do we know anything about all possible degree 3 field extensions?

If characteristic is 3:

- If Galois, then Artin-Schreier.
- If inseparable, then this is just cube root.
- If separable, but not normal, then what???

If characteristic is not 3 (automatically separable):

- If Galois, then this come from adjoining a cube root or not? (some people told me yes, some no)
- What if non-Galois?

Anyone know the answer to these? Thanks.

Comment: it would be nice if you added some examples for the parts you think already knowing, because many of us don't.

Comment: Maybe I'll answer later if I find the time, but here's an example to keep in mind: the splitting field of $8x^3+4x^2-4x-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$: the complex roots are $\cos(2k\pi/7)$, the extension is Galois with group cyclic of order $3$ (a generator sending $\cos(2\pi/7)$ to $\cos(4\pi/7)$), and it is *not* obtained by adjoining a rational cube root because the Galois closure of a cubic root over $\mathbb{Q}$ must be of degree $6$. In fact it can't be solved by real cube roots: this is the classical *casus irreducibilis* of the Vieta/Cardan method.

Comment: To extend @Gro-Tsen’s comment, I’ll say that *any* normal cubic extension of $\Bbb Q$ must be totally real (and Gro-Tsen exhibits just one of the infinitely many of these), while a normal extension involving cube root will automatically have the cube roots of unity, quadratic over $\Bbb Q$, so such a field will be of even total degree over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Lubin what do you mean by 'cube roots of unity (are) quadratic over $\mathbb{Q}$'?

Comment: I mean,  @gen ,  that the primitive cube roots of unity are the solutions of $X^2+X+1=0$.